# How to implement custom design for specific views in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am working on my application. I need to implement custome design for my specific view. I don't know how to do this.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in the view. On the right side there is an option 'Advanced'. When you will click on it. it will expend and there is an option Theme. when you will click on it a popup will open and it will show various style option. Click on any specific option then it will show the code for it. Copy the code and keep it in a new file in editor, Save this file with the name that is given as option for the selected style option. Save this file under `"your_project_path/sites/all/themes/your_theme/template/"` and and there is an option to re-scan in the open theme popup. click on re-scan. You file will be show as bold. Hit save button ans save the view.

Now you can template your view in this file. Hope it will help you. 
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this theming instructions:

https://www.drupal.org/node/352970

There are a lot tutorials and documentations on theming views, just search for them.

Comment: Thanks for this important link